# Error when parsing string to int

Tags: java, android

Im generating 2 random values and in EditText you need to enter a result of adding this 2 values and when im tring to parse that what i get from edittext it crash my application

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int wynik;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtv);

    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = (r.nextInt(100 - 1) + 1);
    int i2 = (r.nextInt(100 - 1) + 1);
    text.setText(i1 +" + " + i2 + " = ");
    wynik =i1+i2;
};
    public void backtomain(View view)
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        String etstring =editText.getText().toString();
        Integer etint = Integer.parseInt(etstring); <---------------- CRASH CUZ OF THIS LINE

        //if(etint==wynik)
        //{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AalarmActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("toggleBtn", true);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Toast.makeText(this, "Error ",
        //            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //}
    }
}
```

Commented lines are not finished first need to repair that parsing part.

Comment: How does it crash? Please post a complete crash log/stack trace.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick @Reigertje

Comment: Probably your input is not a number. Put `android:inputType="number"` in the XML

Comment: android:inputType="number" solved a problem thanks @DeividiCavarzan

Comment: Ok, I will post this as answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashing due to Integer.parseInt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292169/crashing-due-to-integer-parseint)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably is receiving a input that is not a number.

You can force to use the input type as mumber, modify your `EditText` in XML and include this property:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

This will force to user input only numbers, and your `Integer.parseInt(etstring);` should parse the number without format exceptions.